# Javascript hide don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, hide

I tried to hide an image with `class="hide_phone"` but both code above didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function($){
   $('.hide_phone').hide();
 });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function($){
   $('.hide_phone').css('display','none');
 });
</script>
```

Why? I think they are ok writed... I put this javascript in header/footer of an wordpress ecommerce theme, after jquery call. Still dont work anywhere

Comment: Any error in console..? Especially $ not defined..? Basically this error occurs when Jq library is not found..

Comment: It's working fine, actually http://jsfiddle.net/r75K8/

Comment: not need to pass $ as a argument in function

Comment: Is the `class="hide_phone"` rendered later?

Comment: I know it works fine for me too in jsfiddle. First i tried without $ and put it later, i forget it there but is not my problem solution...

Comment: @dragosbd Well we don't have access to your codebase, so no way for us to know where the problem is. Do you get an error message? Have you tried debugging it? Place a breakpoint on that line and see what happens when you hit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include jquery library in page.

Comment: This is not incorrect syntax. This pattern is used to keep a local version of the jQuery variable within the `ready` handler. There is no reason that the OPs code would not work, given the example he has shown.

Comment: I solve this. I put again link to jquery library in page and works. I want to say that jquery was already in header, but god know why it doesn't work...

Thanks guys! Love you like always!